# Completely blank TYPO3 login page (after update)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-6.2.x

I am starting the process of updating TYPO3 to higher versions (from the base 6.2.X version). The process of updating to version 7.6.X was ok. Being logged in 6.2 version, I switched to version 7.6 and updated elements in InstalTool, plugins etc. The problem appears when I log out. After entering my login address, I have a blank page - white page without any code. I can log into InstallTool but unfortunately not to BE.

The [FE] page works fine after the update. Any ideas what went wrong or where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: blank page normally means: there is an error but all error information was disabled.

If you just changed the source it might be a mismatch between cache and source: clear all caches in Install Tool.

Also your first step should be look into the server log.
If that does not give enough hints enable all debugging and error information in the Install Tool.

If that still gives no clue: disable all extensions (remove from `PackageStates.php` and don't forget to clear caches afterwards, maybe manually too)

Comment: In addition clear the BE-User preferences via Install Tool and all your session cookies in your browser.

Comment: InstallTool cache was cleared dozens of times (after each change). I have debugging turned on and still no errors showing. Unfortunately, disabling plugins (setting the state to "inactive") causes an error that the extension is not loaded. On the same server I have installed a separate, empty installation (also version 7.6) and everything works. I copied the `htaccess` and replaced the entries in `LocalConfiguration.php` but it did not help at all.

Comment: @adrian check for errors in the PHP log and (for these old versons) in `typo3temp/logs/`. The error could also come from the webserver - you might want to try disabling the `.htaccess`.

Comment: After deleting the file `/typo3temp/Cache/Code/cache_core/ext_tables_XXX`, the login screen is available again

Comment: [Here](https://t3terminal.com/blog/typo3-errors/) you find instructions on how to enable error information in TYPO3.